# How to send email id when calling identity server 4 to login

Tags: identityserver4, angular-auth-oidc-client

I have a angular application and identity server 4 application. I have a login page in angular app which have only user name and when user enters his username , **i want to send this username to IDs 4** and based on his username i will ask him to login either using password or redirect to AZure AD (i have saved these settings in DB which mode he needs to login).

From angular we are only able to call this method `this.oidcSecurityService.authorize();` 
Can anyone suggest the way to send the username to IS4 from angular application using the angular-auth-oidc-client library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenID Connect [authorization requests](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) can include the username in the `login_hint` parameter. IdentityServer will then make that available to you via the `IIdentityServerInteractionService`.

Your client library should allow you to set this query string parameter for authorization requests.

Comment: in this angular-auth-oidc-client library , i couldn't find any way to add username in query string when calling ID server , but yes as you mentioned it should have. so should i have to use different library then?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/blob/master/API_DOCUMENTATION.md#setcustomrequestparametersparams--key-string-string--number--boolean- to set the parameter manually

Comment: Thanks , its my bad that i have missed this clear documentation . In future i will not do this thing.

Comment: Updated above link : https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/blob/main/docs/public-api.md

Comment: both links above are broken.